# Cordova Map not loading in Framework7

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, html-framework-7

I am trying to integrate cordova google map in Framework7 html but its not display any map there although I have write similar code for normal html page and its working there. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var GOOGLE = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(37.422858, -122.085065);
    var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(mapDiv);
    map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, function () {
        map.setCenter(GOOGLE);
    });

}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You might need to use [`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener), try to use domlistener within `deviceready` to load [google library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) asynchronously.

```
*function loadAsynchronousScript() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +'&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
document.body.appendChild(script);
}*
```

Try to play around with demo app, this demo app uses Google Maps SDK for cordova: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Comment: Yasir asked about cordova-plugin-googlemaps, not google maps javascript API v3.